# (SystemJS) host is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, systemjs

i'm trying to compile an example (example 9) of new Y.Fain's book "Angular 2 Development with TypeScript" (the source code is located here: https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/b/73714e3-d07f-48b3-9c14-a8d65754e51f/angular2_typescript_source_code.zip) and I got follow error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: (SystemJS) host is undefined
base64encode@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:12079:1
getSourceMappingURL@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:73929:43
printSourceFileOrBundle@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:74550:36
emitJsFileOrBundle@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:74499:13
emitSourceFileOrBundle@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:74456:13
forEachEmittedFile@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:74365:30
emitFiles@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:74446:9
emitWorker@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:78992:30
emit/<@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:78952:66
runWithCancellationToken@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:79043:24
emit@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:78952:20
transpileModule@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:96252:9
transpile@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:96261:22
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:17
Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:138:24
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:872:29
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:421:17
Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:188:28
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:595:25
ZoneTask.invokeTask@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:500:21
invokeTask@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1540:9
globalZoneAwareCallback@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1566:17

Error loading http://localhost:8080/client/app/main.ts
```

I have installed all necessary env like he described here: https://yakovfain.com/2015/10/13/starting-an-angular-2-project-with-typescript-and-jspm/
npm, typescript, http-server
in systemjs.config.js I have added baseURL param

```
baseURL: "/client",
```

Comment: **Side note**: I would recommend using the angular cli instead of using systemjs. There are plenty of tutorials out there on how to do this including those found on the angular web site.

Comment: Yes, I agree but I'm trying to understand what's wrong with SystemJS and System object as I presume. I got this error with all book's examples

Comment: I also had the same issue although I used old dependencies version. Probably something with NodeJS or other stuff

Answer (score 0):

For me, changing the package.json file from:

```
"typescript": "^2.0.0"
```

to:

```
"typescript": "~2.0.0"
```

solved it.

Had to "npm i" and restart the server before the fix appeared.

See [Documentation](https://github.com/Farata/angular2typescript/commit/d183aff53205718f5e080e4a645b3f699039faae#diff-c5924286af307b5f775b65f389907c06R24]Fix) for more info.